# Rewrite array without second temp array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$a = array(
        array(
            'a' => 'x',
            'b' => 'asdasd',
        ),
        array(
            'a' => 'f',
            'b' => '123123qwe',
        ),
);
```

And I expect an array like this:

```
$a = array(
        'asdasd',
        '123123qwe',
);
```

I can transform this by iterating and filling a new array,
I wonder if I can do this in 1 line without temporary variables?

Update: Using PHP 5.3 , thanks for the 5.5 suggestions tho!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old school method (pre 5.5):

```
<?php
function simplify($el)
{
    return $el['b'];
}
$a = array(
        array(
            'a' => 'x',
            'b' => 'asdasd',
        ),
        array(
            'a' => 'f',
            'b' => '123123qwe',
        ),
);
$a = array_map('simplify',$a);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($a,true).'</pre>';
```

5.3 method with anonymous function:

```
$a = array_map(function($el){return $el['b'];},$a);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($a,true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Bah… Was just about to post that too… +1

Comment: I'm using this code: `array_map(function($e) { return $e['b']; }, $a),true)`

Comment: @DanFromGermany You mean you were already using that method and wanted an alternative to that? Or you are using it now?

Comment: I took your code and changed it to use the anon function, posted that comment just when you added it to your answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using PHP 5.5 you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
 $new_array = array_column($a, 'b');
```

**[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/CQAI2)**

Comment: I love `5.5` functions and classes but we are using `5.3` in production :-( +1 anyways